# Java for loop [method]

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, methods

hi all i want ask how can get out |pc| from for loop to anthor method like getPlayer or etc

```
        for (L2PcInstance pc : L2World.getInstance().getPlayers())
    {
        if (pc.isOnline() && ((pc.getClient() != null) && !pc.getClient().isDetached()))
        {
            Object[] rowData = new Object[]
            {
                pc.getAccountName(),
                pc.getId(),
                pc.getName(),
                pc.getLevel(),
                pc.getCurrentHp(),
                pc.getCurrentMp(),
                pc.getCurrentCp(),
                pc.getPvpKills(),
                pc.getPkKills(),
                pc.getBaseClass(),
                pc.getCreateDate()
            };
            model.addRow(rowData);
        }

    }
```

im try everything but not work can give me someone explame :( 
in my idea is like this

```
private L2PcInstance pc;
for (pc : L2World.getInstance().getPlayers())

public L2PcInstance getPlayer()
{
return pc;
}
```

thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `break` if you want to move out of the for loop and make a call to any method as required.

```
    for (L2PcInstance pc : L2World.getInstance().getPlayers())
        {
            if (pc.isOnline() && ((pc.getClient() != null) && !pc.getClient().isDetached()))
            {
                Object[] rowData = new Object[]
                {
                    pc.getAccountName(),
                    pc.getId(),
                    pc.getName(),
                    pc.getLevel(),
                    pc.getCurrentHp(),
                    pc.getCurrentMp(),
                    pc.getCurrentCp(),
                    pc.getPvpKills(),
                    pc.getPkKills(),
                    pc.getBaseClass(),
                    pc.getCreateDate()
                };
                model.addRow(rowData);
            }
break;

        }

//call a new method here
```

Comment: `break` is not a method, but a keyword, so it should be just `break;`

Comment: Its not work mm for me need me the Initialization out of the loop and get the result in anthor method

Comment: You can define 'model' out of the for loop and it will be updated within the for loop and the end result of model can be passed to different method as an argument.

However, 'break' can be used on selective basis i.e. you can define some condition to break out of the loop.

Comment: mm thanks this work now :)